# Google Maps - Use React to Make List Clickable

Tags: reactjs, list, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, clickable

I need to make the sidebar list clickable so when you click on a location on the sidebar, its corresponding marker will open the infowindow.  Below is the code I used:

Click List function:

```
clickListItem = venues => {
    const marker = this.state.markers.find(marker.id === venues.id);
    this.handleMarkerClick(marker);
    console.log(venues.name);
  };
```

Then I tried to call it on the sidebar:

```
<List>
            {this.props.venues &&
              this.props.venues.map(({ venue }, index) => (
                <ListItem
                  button
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => this.props.clickListItem(this.props)}
                >
                  <ListItemText primary={venue.name} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
          </List>
```

When I click on a location, nothing happens. How do I get the list to call the marker function that opens the infowindow? Full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/73l3j8m6j).

Answer (score 0):

Sidebar.js, line 154. For a start, try changing that to:

`onClick={() => this.props.clickListItem(venue)}`